# Laravel views: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I have a views and i would like to display the records that is in the database

- ID
- LastName
- Firstname
- Phone

But he shows me this error :

> FatalErrorException in 6361dda302a0f162671ee5b36a4abe93 line 26:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

**welcome.blade.php :**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Welcom!
@endsection 

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <legend>List</legend>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>lastaname</th>
              <th>firstname</th>
              <th>phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @if (count($customers) > 0 )
                @foreach($customers->all() as $customer)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ $customer->id }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $customer->lastaname }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $customer->firstname }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $customer->phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                 @enforeach
            @endif
          </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**CreatesController :**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Customer;

class CreatesController extends Controller {

    public function welcome()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view('welcome', ['customers' => $customers]);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `@endforeach` instead of `@enforeach`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops

Laravel expects you close `@foreach` first, that's why it throws the exception.